# WordPress: how to hide toolbar in post editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type (Products) in my WordPress web site.

This is a WooCommerce Product, if it's necessary to know.

I need to hide toolbar (1) into wp-editor on Add Product page.
Also I need to hide "Add media" button (2) and "Visual/Text" tabs (3).

How do I hide them?

Maybe it make sense to change this WordPress Editor to the textarea with the same value of "name" attribute with using of some hooks?

[image: how to hide toolbar in post editor?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution:

```
    function hide_toolbar_TinyMCE( $in ) {
        $in['toolbar1'] = '';
        $in['toolbar2'] = '';
        $in['toolbar'] = false;
        return $in; 
    }
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'hide_toolbar_TinyMCE' );
```

But it hide toolbar everywhere, because this is "filter" but not "action".
How do I hide it only on Product (Custom Post Type) Add/Edit page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use function.php or plugin to manage this code.You need to put a action.

**Remove media button:**

```
function z_remove_media_controls() {
     remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
}
 add_action('admin_head','z_remove_media_controls');
```

**Remove Visual tab**

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'custom_edit_page_js', 99);

function custom_edit_page_js(){ 
echo '  <style type="text/css">
        a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover, #qt_content_fullscreen{
            display:none;
        }
        </style>';
echo '  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#content-tmce").attr("onclick", null);
        });
        </script>'; 
}
```

You can Identify post type is,

```
if( get_post_type() == 'product' && is_admin()) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But I need to remove it only on Add Product page.

Comment: hi,you can check post type

Comment: I just edit a post for ,"I need to remove it only on Add Product page."

Comment: On current Wordpress (~5.2) with classic editor, following CSS rule will hide the `Text/Visual` tab thing: `.wp-editor-tabs { display:none;}`. (The third point in the image of the question).

Comment: @Felix `add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', array($this, 'default_editor') ); ` will do the job as well

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199919/127468) this elegant solution:

```
function wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings( $settings, $editor_id ) {
    if ( $editor_id === 'content' && get_current_screen()->post_type === 'custom_post_type' ) {
        $settings['tinymce']   = false;
        $settings['quicktags'] = false;
        $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
    }

    return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'wpse_199918_wp_editor_settings', 10, 2 );
```