# Remove toolbar from single wp_editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

I have the following code to remove toolbar, media buttons, and visual buttons on my wp_editor. The code is working, but I want it to only remove the items from one wp_editor, not all. Any help is appreciated.

**Wp_editor code**

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'message';
$settings = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'message',
    'textarea_rows' => 10,
);
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

**Code to hide items**

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = '';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar'] = false;
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', function($settings) {
    $settings['media_buttons']=FALSE;
    $settings['quicktags']=FALSE;
    return $settings;
});
```

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865699/wordpress-how-to-hide-toolbar-in-post-editor

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's where I actually got part of my code from, but it doesn't answer my question. I need to remove the controls on just one wp_editor, but this removes the controls on all of them.

Comment: You mean you want to remove it for one post type?

Comment: I'm creating a simple contact form plugin. I want the wp_editor in that plugin to hide all the toolbars, add media, and visual/text buttons. The problem is I have some other wp_editors on the site that I still need the controls to show, but when I activate the contact plugin, it hides the buttons on all wp_editors.

Answer (score 1):

You can set tinymce setting in editor settings

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'message';
$settings = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'message',
    'textarea_rows' => 10,
    'tinymce'       => array(
        'toolbar1'      => '',
        'toolbar2'      => '',
        'toolbar3'      => '',
    ),
);
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $args );
```